# Looking for a comic book about space travel and a royal family

Tags: story-identification, spaceship

I read this probably 15-20 years ago.  It was a large comic book, probably called a graphic novel now. Maybe half an inch thick or a bit less.  It opened with the interior of a royal throneroom in a spaceship totally decked out with roses.  I remember there just being roses everywhere.  There was a princess and later on a whole crew of people. Sorry if it's a bit vague about the storyline.  The one character that stood out to me was a slave boy who looked to be African (or similiar) and he was pyrokinetic.  He was the lover of one of his male shipmates on the spaceship.  The art was not japanese, and seemed to be from the 70-90s era.

Comment: Could it have been French? Reminds me of one of the issues of *Valérian: agent spatio-temporel*.

Comment: This also reminds me of the Metabarons series which was published starting in INCAL around the early 80's

Answer (score 4):

This is *A Distant Soil* by [Colleen Doran](http://adistantsoil.com/).

Jason and Liana were born on Earth but their father was an exile from another planet called Ovanan. He should have been killed (according to their laws) but was spared by Seren, the Avatar. The pyrokinetic you're thinking of is a "slave" held by Seren, but is actually his lover, D'mer.

Other characters include a policeman, a Soviet author (who had defected to the US), and Sir Galahad (who fell through a time portal and ended up being found by Liana). All were recruited by Seren and D'mer.

It's been published in several different versions. Probably the Image Comics graphic novels will be the easiest to find.